# MSSQL Select Distinct combine last column

Tags: php, sql-server

My database output looks as follows:

```
2016-02-03 Ticket1 4.25
2016-02-04 Ticket2 .25
2016-02-04 Ticket2 1.00
2016-02-05 Ticket3 .75
```

How can I run make the query select Distinct so im not seeing duplicate from column1 and column2 but combine the last row so the output would look like:

```
2016-02-03 Ticket1 4.25
2016-02-04 Ticket2 1.25
2016-02-05 Ticket3 .75
```

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col3) AS col3 FROM table_name GROUP BY col1, col2`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you already tried, your current piece of code (and if thrown the errors). We will help you fixing it but aren't the ones writing it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
SELECT column1, column2, SUM(column3) as column3
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY column1, column2;
```